# Will my hard-drive wear/damage when I tilt my laptop?

Tags: torque

I have an old laptop that I turn off every 2 months or so, it's always on, and I use it whenever I need to do something away from my desk, where I have my real machine.

Anyway, every time I grab the laptop (which was laying flat on my desk), I tilt it 90 degrees and hold it under my arm for moving. I noticed that every single time I tilt it, I hear a sound which closely resembles the word "tuck".

I've finally had an idea about what could it be. My best guess is the torque on the hard disk wants to keep its orientation, so the disk moves slightly and touches something when I tilt the laptop quickly.

Could the torque really do such a thing?
I also know that hard-drives are pretty darn solid, so, could the torque have worn out whatever thingie holds the rotating disk to allow it to move as such?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://superuser.com/

Comment: More like electronics SE

Comment: Torque totally belongs to physics last time I checked. I basically asked if a spinning disk with the properties of those often found in hard-drives could act as I presumed it did.

Comment: The click sound is more likely the arm that the drive heads are mounted on moving locking into place to prevent damage.  Most drives have accelerometers in them now and get the heads away from the platters to prevent damage like what you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a platter or disc that spins at a high speed inside the drive.  When you physically move it you can cause the head to miss-align, especially if you move or shock it with a jerky motion.

That sound you're hearing is the hard drive's head trying to re-align itself and continue reading/writing.  It's not a good sound and you could be shortening the life of your hard drive by moving it.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_crash for more info on how hard drives work and how they try to avoid damage from motion.

Comment: So it could be parking the head when it senses the tilt..?

Comment: @Vercas depends if your drive has active protection or not.  It could also be a sign it is dieing because it is attempting to re-align http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death .  You'll have to look it up for your laptop.  Parking the head or realignment will cause that sound.